# fatal error pls solve for me

Tags: module, database

I declare `data.php` file inside this code

```
 <?php
 class Test_Tes_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
 {

 } 
 ?>
```

and config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Tes>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_Tes>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <Tes>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Tes</module>
                    <frontName>Tes</frontName>
                </args>
            </Tes>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Tes>
                    <file>Tes.xml</file>
                </Tes>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <Tes>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Tes</module>
                    <frontName>Tes</frontName>
                </args>
            </Tes>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <Test_Tes>
                <title>Tes</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>              
                <children>
                    <items module="[module]">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>Tes/adminhtml_Tes</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </Test_Tes>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Tes>
                            <title>Tes Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </Tes>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>  
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Tes>
                    <file>Tes.xml</file>
                </Tes>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>  
    <global>
        <models>
            <Tes>
                <class>Test_Tes_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Tes_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </Tes>
            <Tes_mysql4>
                <class>Test_Tes_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <Tes>
                        <table>Tes</table>
                    </Tes>
                </entities>
            </Tes_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <Tes_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Test_Tes</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </Tes_setup>
            <Tes_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>


            </Tes_write>
            <Tes_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </Tes_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <Tes>
                <class>Test_Tes_Block</class>
            </Tes>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <Tes>
                <class>Test_Tes_Helper</class>
            </Tes>
        </helpers>
        <admin>
       <routers>
           <!-- Includes our controller, so when we add the adminhtml menu item below, it is found! -->
           <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Tes before="Mage_Adminhtml">Test_Tes_Adminhtml</Tes>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
       </routers>
   </admin>
   <adminhtml>
       <menu>
           <Tes module="Tes">
               <title>Tes</title>
               <sort_order>71</sort_order>              
               <children>
                   <items module="Tes">
                       <title>Manage Items</title>
                       <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                       <action>adminhtml/Tes</action>
                   </items>
               </children>
           </Tes>
       </menu> 
    </adminhtml>

    </global>

</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<items module="[module]">` with `<items module="Test_Tes">` in your config file and the tag `<Tes>` under `<entities>` with `<tes>` (lowercase)